# Nginx strips cookie on websocket upgrade

Tags: javascript, nginx

Hopefully this helps anyone surprised by this quirk. I have a node server that sets a jwt auth token in a cookie and then upgrades the https to wss. Before the nginx reverse proxy everything worked and the cookie did its job but now that I have nginx in between with a CSP I’m noticing the cookie is gone and then the CSP gives a connect-src error. Not sure what happened. I have a redirect for naked domains to https and the full domain name with www so not sure if that is changing the src or removing the cookie. Everything works until the wss. I have ws: and wss: set in the CSP so it should let it pass.

What is nginx doing on the wss upgrade to strip the cookie? I’ve looked all over for the solution including some proxy headers for cookies but I don’t think that’s the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Been working on this for days now.

Comment: Any luck since then?